# Reuse gulp.src to inject same source in different files using gulp-inject

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm automating a new angular project and I'm using **gulp-inject** to grab all of my project script dependencies and inject them in order. The source scripts is a merge of many different streams using **streamqueue** and I have two tasks that use the same result from streamqueue to inject the scripts paths, one in my index.html file and another in my karma.conf.js file. To avoid repetition of code and posible errors I moved this to a function like this

```
function getAppDependencies() {
    'use strict';
    return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
        gulp.src('./wwww/js/*.js', { read: false }),
        gulp.src(paths.app + '/**/*.module.js').pipe(filesort()),
        gulp.src([paths.app + '/**/*.js', '!' + paths.app + '/**/*.module.js', '!' + paths.app + '/**/*.routes.js'], { read: false }),
        gulp.src([paths.app + '/**/*.routes.js'], { read: false }),
        gulp.src('./www/mocks/*.js', { read: false })
    );
}
```

Both tasks looks very similar. This is the task for karma

```
gulp.task('inject:karma', function () {
   'use strict';
   var deps = getAppDependencies(),
       tranfFn = function (filepath, file, i, length) {
           return '  "./' + filepath + '"' + (i + 1 < length ? ',' : '');
       };
    gulp.src('./tests/karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(inject(deps), {
            starttag: 'files: [',
            endtag: ']',
            transform: tranfFn,
            addRootSlash: false
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tests/'));
});
```

And this is the task for the index.html file

```
gulp.task("inject", function () {
    "use strict";
    var deps = getAppDependencies();
    gulp.src('./www/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(deps, {
            starttag: '<!-- inject:scripts -->',
            addRootSlash: false,
            relative: true
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
 });
```

They basically look the same however the karma task is not working. The files: [] setting of the karma.conf.js is not populated with file paths. I tried to remove the function getAppDependencies and include the streamqueue block directly and it worked.

```
    gulp.src('./tests/karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(inject(streamqueue({ objectMode: true } 
        // stream arguments ....
```

I also notice that the inject tasks output *"Starting inject..."* in the console but they never output *"Finished inject..."*. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.